# hta internet explorer application

Tags: php, excel, internet-explorer

I have a php file on our intranet and I need to create a script to:

1. load another php file (on the intranet too)
2. save it as local **mht** file
3. open the mht with Excel
4. display Excel with the mht

(this is enforced by my hierarchy)

I create a hta file and load it from javascript in the first php.
This work well *except in windows 10, (I use IE , not Edge)*

- then using the IE object and changing his visible state to false, IE still appears,
- then waiting using then .busy function, the loop never finish
- Strange: if I change the url ( for example, using http://google.com) the script work well.

---

**Summary of the hta file**

```
<script language=vbs>
Dim WS, FS, URL, Path, Title
Sub SaveAsMhtml()
    Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    On Error Resume Next
' for example
    URL= "http://mysite/myphp.php?what=1"
'with this following url, all is OK
'URL="http://google.com"
    Title="test.mht"
    Path = "C:\temp\"
    If Not FS.FolderExists(Path) Then FS.CreateFolder Path
    set IE=CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Navigate URL
' this line do nothing in W10
        .visible=false
' this do not work in w10 too
'       Do While .Busy: Loop
        ' create the mht
        With CreateObject("CDO.Message")
            On Error Resume Next
            .CreateMHTMLBody(URL)
            FS.CreateTextFile Path & Title 
            .BodyPart.GetStream.SaveToFile Path & Title , 2
        End With
' this line create an execution error in w10
        .Quit
    End With
    Set objExcel =CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(Path & Title)
    objExcel.visible=true
    window.close
End Sub
</script>
```

So where is my error ?
Or is it another solution to solve my initial need ? (without the hta if possible)

Comment: As far as I am aware, you can't run PHP code within an HTA.

Comment: the Php code is inside the php file

Comment: and it is executed like if I open the php directly with the browser

Comment: PHP is a server-side language, you can't just open it in the browser, it won't work.

Comment: sorry, but it work

Comment: I have the result on my screen and my problem is not the execution of the php but the comportement of the internetexplorer object